# How to create a Heading with 2 different colors with the color-change ocurring in a letter?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a heading in two colors, black and white. The color change should occur in the letter, so I can't use span. The Heading is "Modern Art Gallery". I want the change to happen in the letter 'n'. (See example image below.)

I tried to use a filter but that didn't work. Now I am trying to use two headings, one in white and one in black, but when I position them on top of each other I only see one of them, depending on the z-index.

[image: example]

Comment: When you post a question like this, try to add code snippets of what you tried. So we can see what you already tried and see if you are on the correct path. It might just be that you are nearly there and just need a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mix-blend-mode for this.
Make the background the split black and white and the color of the text white.

The difference between black and white is #fff (ie white) and the difference between white and white is #000 (ie black)

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 0 50%, white 50% 100%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1>GALLERY</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this. An extended guide can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/.

As an example you could try the following method. You create a parent and child element, in this example we chose <header> and <h2>. Then make sure the header and the h2 have identical backgrounds and that these backgrounds perfectly overlap. Then set color: transparent on the h2 and clip its background to text.

The final step is to set filter: invert(1) on the h2. For black and white text you can set the filter: invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(9)

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0 }

header {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/2017/17_04_cat_bg_03.jpg) 50%/ cover
}

h2 {
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
          background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font: 900 35vmin/50vh cookie, cursive;
  text-align: center;
  filter: invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(9);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h2>Give this a try</h2>
</header>
```